# Haphazard code execution flow after function integration in workspace. (Renesas MCU, HEW IDE)

Tags: debugging, embedded, microcontroller, execution, freertos

MCU: Renesas RX62N
IDE: HEW

I am experiencing a strange program execution flow after I integrated a SD Card handler routine in the workspace which was previously running sequentially as it should.

For a Function

```
L1  : Void func(unint8_t arg)
L2  : { 
L3  :  static uint8_t testVar=0;
L4  :  
L5  :  testVar = arg;
L6  :  testVar = (testVar/2)   ;
L7  : 
L8  :  integratedFunction(&structureX);
L9  :  
L10 :  printf("/nTest Print/n");
L11 : }
L12 :
L13 : void integratedFunction(pSTRUCT pCard)
L14 : {
L15 :  static uint32_t ulVariable = 100;
L16 :  pCard->crdNo =0;
L17 :  pCard->crdType = CARD_TYPE;
L18 :                       
L...:  // other lines of assignment to update card structure
L26 :  ulVariable--;
L27 :  
L28 :  }
L29 :
```

The execution flow must be from top to bottom sequentially. It must go to L1 (Line 1), so on to L5, L6 then L8 (then L13,L16,L17...L26) and at the end to L10.

But the problem I am facing is that after the

```
integratedFunction();
```

is called, the  execution of lines of code in side the integratedFunction() is NOT SEQUENTIAL.

The microcontroller goes to the L13 when the integratedFunction is called, then jumps to L19 directly, then to L16, then to L23 then to an other line in some other function.... [Please note I used an E1 debugger to find out such a behavior]. When the integratedFunction is tested alone separately it executes sequentially as it should.

One more thing, the memory locations assigned to the lines of code are the in the same incremental order as the code is executing in the haphazard manner i.e PC counter is incrementing as it should, its just the matter why were the memory location not assigned to lines of code in integrated function in the incremental fashion as its flow suggests.

What might be a probable cause for such an erratic behavior?

Comment: Do you have compiler optimizations turn on high?

Comment: NO, All Optimization turned off (No speed and size optimization)

Comment: Maybe try a clean rebuild of everything.  The debug symbols may have gotten out of sync with the source code.  If you're sure optimizations are off and a rebuild all doesn't help then look at the interlaced assembly while you're debugging and see if you can make sense of it.

Comment: I did try that but it did not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sure the program is single threaded sequential, and does not for example use a timer interrupt?  SD card access can require substantial waits, so it's not uncommon to use a timer to complete some tasks.  Another possibility if you are simply busy waiting could be allowing a watchdog timer to expire, and restarting the program as a result.  Not saying either of these is your cause, but it's something to keep in mind / rule out.

Comment: You have mentioned L19 and L23 in the text but chosen to elide them in the code - that's not too helpful!

Comment: Occam's razor suggests that despite your assertion, optimisation is enabled.  Look at the build log output to see what compiler options are applied.  Maybe even post that log as evidence of you assertion.

Comment: @ChrisStratton 
The program is running FreeRTOS. Agreed that SD card access required substantial wait, I even called the integratedFunction before starting the scheduler. Lets for a moment forget the execution, As I compile the code and upload it via a debugger, why are the memory location not assigned sequentially to the integratedFunction(). Just to look at the flow even before the execution.

Comment: @Clifford
The lines which I have not shown are simple assignment statements for SPI configuration registers.

Comment: In the map file I do see

-nooptimize

Comment: @Osaid: That was not my point.  What I wanted to see was whether the execution order affected the result - i.e. whether the reordering was equivalent.  If it was important enough to mention it was important enough to include - after all you have included many other lines not mentioned in your description.  Regarding the build log, the map file is not the same thing, and saying it in a comment is not the same as *updating and improving the question* by adding the diagnostic information likely to be necessary to answer your question.

Comment: The compiler is free to re-order operations and cache values in registers, in ways that give the same result.  If some operations have side effects such as being access to memory mapped hardware SPI registers, then declaring those variables *volatile* will require the compiler to actually access them, and in order.  Otherwise it has a lot of latitude.

Comment: @Clifford
The execution order is indeed affecting the required result. Concerning your point of including all the lines, I purposely did not mention the lines because code is too large. The situation presented was merely symbolic, to get an idea what scenario might result such a behaviour. Alright I will include the code momentarily.

Comment: An embedded system built while I was a student functioned "randomly" in a manner not so different that what is described. The system used data tables to guide execution. When the application was ported from the development system to embedded target, a memory map error was made (transposed address digits). In this case, the stack reached into the data space. Since the data controlling execution flow was static, the system operated without trashed-stack behavior, but, the corrupted data space caused "properly executing functions" to execute in bizarre but systematic order.

Comment: Check the stack size that you have allocated